# Vector's cross product and if statement in function

Tags: python, if-statement, vector

My program is working but not all of it's parts, I listed my problems in comment of program

```
class MyVector:
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector

    def get_vector(self):
        return self.vector

    def __mul__(self, other):
        scalar_result = 0  # or 0.0
        for i in range(0, len(self.vector)):
            scalar_result += self.vector[i] * other.vector[i]
        return scalar_result

    def is_perpendicular_to(self, other):       #is there a way that I could make function which will print wheter they are perpendicular or not?
        if (scalar_result == 0):                #this isn't seem to work
            print("They are perpendicular")

    """
    Also I was hoping that I can get crossdot product of these two vectors, but I can not make it functional
    def crossProd(vector):
        dimension = len(a)
        c = []
        for i in range(dimension):
            c.append(0)
            for j in range(dimension):
                if j <> i:
                    for k in range(dimension):
                        if k <> i:
                            if k > j:
                                c[i] += a[j] * b[k]
                            elif k < j:
                                c[i] -= a[j] * b[k]
        return c
    """

if __name__ == "__main__":
     vec1 = MyVector([1, 0, 3, 0])
     vec2 = MyVector([0, 4, 0, 4])
     print(vec1.get_vector())
     print(vec2.get_vector())
     scalar_result = vec1 * vec2
     print(scalar_result)
```

In the upper part I created logical algorithm that I think should work, but I can't put it to the program, for me it is not functional

Comment: The variable `scalar_result` is local to the `__mul__` function. You can't access it in `is_perpendicular_to`. And `is_perpendicular_to` never does `self * other`, so what's supposed to set the variable?

Comment: I think you just want `if self * other == 0:`

Comment: If you have multiple questions, you should post them separately.

Comment: "for me it is not function" is not a clear question. What is it supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: My question is, how should look a function which print "They are perpendicular" if scalar_result = 0.

Comment: `if vec1.is_perpendicular(vec2): print "They are pependicular"`

Comment: `is_perpendicular()` should return `True` or `False`, not print something by itself.

Comment: this question seems to be all about `python`, not `c`.  Suggest removing the `c` tag

Comment: strange, I tried it and this shows up "" TypeError: is_perpendicular_to() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) "", I don't get it vec 2 is just 1 argument? or not?